# Can I just use fixed arrays instead of memory pools?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, memory-pool

Instead of making a memory pool system,can't I just allocate huge arrays for each object at the start of the application and just use them and in the extreme case some object does need more instances than it's array,the array will just get doubled or quadrupled in size,so it would never reach the maximum size again.I need speed more than memory,so I think it's a fair trade off?

Comment: How is that different from a memory pool?

Comment: That's how memory pools are usually implemented.

Comment: How would that be faster? It sounds like it would be slower since you'll be creating as many as twice as many objects as you need and creating objects takes time.

Comment: One, of course not, two, profile on your own to determine you need this speed improvement, three, advisable to accept answers to your questions.

Answer (score 5):

The only difference between what you are describing and a memory pool, is that usually, a pool allocator would allocate a new pool when it runs out of memory, yours would reallocate the entire array if it runs out. That would result in a greatly increased worst-case runtime and you would need a scheme to avoid invalidating pointers and references when you reallocate, which would probably lower performance for the whole program.

The worst case in a pool-allocator is when it runs out of space and has to allocate a new array. The worst case in your allocator, it runs out and has to allocate a new larger array and copy all of the old objects over to new array. Clearly the latter will take much more time.